# How to retrieve each string item from the array in plist

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, xamarin

I have the following plist where I need to get `keyItem1` and `keyItem2` to assign it to `string[]`. I could able to get the items but could not able to assign it to string array. I am using Xamarin, but objective C would be helpful as well.

**Code**

```
string settingsBundle = NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource ("MySettings.bundle/Root", @"plist");
NSDictionary dic = NSDictionary.FromFile (settingsBundle);
var contacts = dic.ObjectForKey (new NSString ("keyarray1"));
```

**MySettings.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>keyarray1</key>
<array>
    <string>keyitem1</string>
    <string>keyitem2</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: What type is contacts?  Is it a NSArray?

Comment: Can you cast it to NSArray?

Comment: Yes I can cast it as an NSArray

Comment: Then you should be able to iterate over the array to get the values out.